# ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer una captura de pantalla pero solo un "div" usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, screenshot

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacer un screenshot usando javascript, Encontre como hacer un screenshot de toda la pantalla pero lo que necesito es hacer la captura de solo lo que contiene un div.

Quiza me puedan ayudar a modificar el script, gracias de antemano.
se utiliza **html2canvas.** 
El script es el siguiente:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {   onrendered (canvas) {
    var link = document.getElementById('descargar');;
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    link.href = image;
    link.download = 'carputarpantalla.png';   }  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólo debes colocar tu div en lugar del body

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#tu-div")).then(canvas => {         
    let image = canvas.toDataURL();
    let link = document.getElementById('descargar');
    link.href = image;
    link.download = 'carputarpantalla.png';
});
```